# ORA-01843 "not a valid month" and ORA-01861 "literal does not match format string"

Tags: sql, database, oracle, date-arithmetic

```
SQL> select to_timestamp('2010-12-14:09:56:53') - to_timestamp('2010-12-14:09:56:46') from dua
l;
select to_timestamp('2010-12-14:09:56:53') - to_timestamp('2010-12-14:09:56:46') from dual
                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01843: not a valid month


SQL> select to_date('2010-12-14:09:56:53') - to_date('2010-12-14:09:56:46') from dual;
select to_date('2010-12-14:09:56:53') - to_date('2010-12-14:09:56:46') from dual
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

What is the correct way to do a

```
2010-12-14:09:56:53
minus
2010-12-14:09:56:46
```

in Oracle SQL?

Comment: This probably shouldn't be tagged sqlplus - how about sql instead

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to specify format that your timestamp string is in to [`TO_DATE`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm) and [`TO_TIMESTAMP`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions193.htm) functions:

```
select 
    to_date('2010-12-14:09:56:53', 'YYYY-MM-DD:HH24:MI:SS') - 
    to_date('2010-12-14:09:56:46', 'YYYY-MM-DD:HH24:MI:SS') 
from dual;
```

Result will be in days, which you can multiply by 86,400 to get seconds:

```
TO_DATE('2010-12-14:09:56:53','YYYY-MM-DD:HH24:MI:SS')-TO_DATE('2010-12-14:09:56
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.000081019
```

---

Using [`TO_TIMESTAMP`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions193.htm):

```
select 
    to_timestamp('2010-12-14:09:56:53', 'YYYY-MM-DD:HH24:MI:SS') - 
    to_timestamp('2010-12-14:09:56:46', 'YYYY-MM-DD:HH24:MI:SS') 
from dual;
```

Result will be in `TIMESTAMP` format:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP('2010-12-14:09:56:53','YYYY-MM-DD:HH24:MI:SS')-TO_TIMESTAMP('2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
+000000000 00:00:07.000000000
```

Answer (score 2):

Use to_timesatmp

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP('2010-12-14:09:56:53',  'YYYY-MM-DD:HH24:MI:SS.FF') 
 - TO_TIMESTAMP('2010-12-14:09:56:46',  'YYYY-MM-DD:HH24:MI:SS.FF') 

from dual
```